# pickle dump method add wierd binary data

Tags: python, binary, pickle, dump

everyone!

I write some binary data using pickle.dump() in a file, and read the file as below code.

```
import numpy as np
import pickle

save_file = open('test.rdb','wb')
save_data = np.array([1, 2, 3])
pickle.dump(np.ndarray.tobytes(save_data),save_file)
save_data = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])

pickle.dump(np.ndarray.tobytes(save_data),save_file)
save_file.close()

read_file = open('test.rdb','rb')
data = read_file.read()
print(data)
```

When I open the file using hex editor, there are some data that I didn't write.
(Red box in the picture below)

[Binary file picture is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM9ca.png)

What are those? and how can I remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest instead of using pickle to dump file, use python default open function to open file in wb and then dump the file. It will not add any extra binary bytes when dumping.

```
binary_file = open('test.rdb', "wb")
binary_file.write(np.ndarray.tobytes(save_data))
binary_file.close()
```